# How to replace file's names with numbers starting with certain number?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, filenames

I want files to be named like 177.jpg, 178.jpg and so on starting with 177.jpg.
I used this to rename them from 1 to amount of files:

```
ls | cat -n | while read n f; do mv "$f" "$n.jpg"; done
```

How to modify this ? But completely new script also would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash can do simple math for you:

```
mv "$f" $(( n + 176 )).jpg
```

Just hope no filename contains a newline.

There are safer ways than parsing the output of `ls`, e.g. iterating over an expanded wildcard:

```
n=177
for f in * ; do
    mv "$f" $(( n++ )).jpg
done
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
#!/bin/bash
c=177;
for i in `ls | grep -v '^[0-9]' | grep .png`; # This will make sure only png files are selected to replace and only the files which have filenames which starts with non-numeric
 do
     mv "$i" "$c".png;
    (( c=c+1 )); 
done
```

Comment: ./1script.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `mv'<br>
./1script.sh: line 4: `     mv $i $c.jpg;'

Comment: looks like you had a line break when you did a copy paste and hence the error.

Comment: Do you mean <br> in comment - no it's only here: I tried to insert <br> in comment.

Comment: It works perfectly for me not sure whats wrong with your version

Comment: I must be screwed up something, it's fine now, thanks.